# Django Rest FrameWork Add Model With User Foreign Key

Tags: django, rest, authentication, foreign-keys, save

I'm using Django version 3 and the Rest Framework, i have a model with  a user foreignkey.
so every time a model is saved the user also need to be saved.
 
To be able to add or to edit  a model via rest you need to be authenticated using token authentication.
I'm using ClassBasedViews, the problem is that i can't find a way to add a model because in my serializer the field user is excluded because i don't want it to be editable.

models.py:

```
class Chambre(models.Model):
    local_id=models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    nom=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank='true')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('local_id', 'user',)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ChambreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Chambre
        exclude =['user',]
```

views.py:

```
class ChambreListApi(APIView):
"""
List all chambres, or create a new chambre.
"""
    authentication_classes=(TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        chambres = Chambre.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = ChambreSerializer(chambres, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ChambreSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(commit=False)
            serializer.user=request.user
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the logic that sets the user to the serializer. By default GenericAPIView will pass the request to the serializer via the context.

```
class ChambreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Chambre
        exclude =['user',]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["user"] = self.context["request"].user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I followed the accepted solution posted by schillingt, I had to add `context={'request': request}` when I instantiated the serializer. The Django REST Framework docs mention adding context to a serializer [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).

### serializers.py

```
class NoteCreateSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        exclude = ['owner',]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['owner'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

### views.py

```
@api_view['POST']
def create_note(request):
    note_serializer = NoteCreateSerializer(
        data = request.data,
        context = {'request': request} # this will populate 'self.context' 
                                       # in the serializer instance
    ) 
    
    # ...
```

Thanks so much for this solution, though! It ended an hours-long struggle.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply that was  very useful, i've solved it by adding method to serializer.py like this :

```
class ChambreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Chambre
        exclude =['user',]


    def set_the_user(self,request):
        self.user=request.user

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["user"] = self.user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

and in the views.py :

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ChambreSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.set_the_user(request)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```